# CJuiDialog with dynamic title

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, dynamic, yii

My question is how to pass title value to CJuiDialog from link or button.

Here's my piece of code that opens CJuiDialog:

```
echo CHtml::link('Add new role', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#new-role-dialog").data("curName", ""); $("#new-role-dialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
```

I tried a lot of different varieties of `$("#new-role-dialog").dialog("title", "My Title")`

Here's similar question to mine: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25142-set-cjuidialog-title-dyanmically/

But none of those advices helped me.

Comment: Check the @Örs answer to see if you've forgot to include the 'id' option.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a CJuiDialog like this

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
      'id'=>'new-role-dialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));
echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

Then call it the same way.

If you want to set the title dynamically, from javascript, you should call

```
$("#new-role-dialog").dialog( "option", "title", "Dialog Title" );
```

More info [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options). 
As a rule of thumb: always check the plugin's original documentation. Yii extensions usually don't have complete API descriptions/examples :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much, next time I'll pay more attention to original documentation